# dismissing a content view

Tags: android, view

After I use setContentView can I dismiss it and set another one?

setting another one does replace the previous but it doesn't release the memory

is there a way to release it from memory?

I used `adb shell dumpsys meminfo <pid>` to show this:

```
                    native   dalvik    other    total
        size:        24836     5703      N/A    30539
   allocated:        23140     3365      N/A    26505
        free:         1559     2338      N/A     3897
       (Pss):         1571     2673    22374    26618
(shared dirty):       1236     4104     2672     8012
(priv dirty):         1512     1928    20552    23992

Objects
       Views:            0        ViewRoots:        0
 AppContexts:            0       Activities:        0
      Assets:            3    AssetManagers:        3
Local Binders:          11    Proxy Binders:       19
Death Recipients:        0
OpenSSL Sockets:         0

SQL
        heap:            0       memoryUsed:        0
pageCacheOverflo:        0  largestMemAlloc:       50
```

Comment: "setting another one does replace the previous but it doesn't release the memory" -- how have you determined this?

Comment: @CommonsWare: I check the memory before and after. do I need to call to GC ? I know it isn't guaranteed, but its better, no?

Comment: "I check the memory before and after" -- and how **precisely** did you do that? There is only one way I know of to detect memory leaks, which is to use MAT. If you used MAT, you can either use it to find the source of your difficulty or you can provide substantially more detail in your question. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html "do I need to call to GC ?" No.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I add more details to the question

Comment: @CommonsWare: well, I'm trying to. I didn't fully understand how to use it. (after the scan). if you know a good guide for this, please post it. what I found wasn't good enough.

Comment: Try http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html and http://youtu.be/_CruQY55HOk

Comment: @CommonsWare: first of all, thank you for your help. well as far as I understood, after doing what it said in the guide you gave me, I don't have memory leaks. it seems that char[] is what takes most memory, but that's a very premature test. what other reasons can it be for a slow down in performance? please reply as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: "what other reasons can it be for a slow down in performance?" -- this has little to do with anything else you have written here. There are no swapfiles or pagefiles in Android, so CPU speed and RAM consumption are largely independent. GC time is about the only place the two overlap, and GC time is not tied to leaks (or the lack thereof). If you are having speed issues, use Traceview or simple logging to find your hotspots, and open a new SO question if you are uncertain of the interpretation of your findings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.gc() call , and try to oblige the Virtual Machine to free memory . You must think that Android is Java , then **the garbage collector is the only way to free memory** anyway it stays .

*P.S:Try to do the call , and if it doesn't release memory in a little time (See LogCat) then come here an show us some source code :) .*